# Python: why I am getting another value than 1?

Tags: python

I have a simple question, why I have got 32/33 after print(len(x)) instead of 1? I see only 1 string every time. What should I do to get 1? I need to get amount of strings and 33/32 is incorrect.

Code:

```
for index, row in df.iloc[0:10].iterrows():
        for x in row['1_5000_pi025']:
            print(x)
            print(len(x))
```

I got:

```
73221_902271_M-34-57-A-a-3-4.tif
32
73221_902617_M-34-57-A-c-1-2.tif
32
73221_902644_M-34-57-A-c-1-4.tif
32
 73221_902642_M-34-57-A-c-3-2.tif
33
73221_902617_M-34-57-A-c-1-2.tif
32
73221_902617_M-34-57-A-c-1-2.tif
32
73221_902268_M-34-57-A-a-4-3.tif
32
73221_902268_M-34-57-A-a-4-3.tif
32
73221_902644_M-34-57-A-c-1-4.tif
32
73221_902644_M-34-57-A-c-1-4.tif
32
73221_902617_M-34-57-A-c-1-2.tif
32
```

Comment: `len` returns the number of characters in the string

Comment: the function ```len``` returns how many characters are in a string

Comment: If `x` is `"73221_902271_M-34-57-A-a-3-4.tif"` then `len(x)` is 32. Hard to see why you'd expect it to be 1.

Comment: How can I return number of strings instead of number of characters?

Comment: If you want to print 1 each time, just `print(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `len` returns the number of characters in a string - for example, the string "foo" would return "3". So, you're not getting the length of the letter x, or how many variables x constitutes, you're getting the length of the string represented by x. If you wanted the length of x itself, try `len('x')`.

Answer (score 0):

The Python [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function returns the length of the argument that’s passed in. If the argument is a `str`, it returns the length of the string(number of characters). If it’s a `list`, it will return the number of indexes in the list.

For instance,

```py
len("73221_902271_M-34-57-A-a-3-4.tif") # returns 32
```

and

```py
len(["73221_902271_M-34-57-A-a-3-4.tif"]) # returns 1
```